# Is it necessary for EM fields to be dependent & co-exist in static conditions?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetics, electromagnetic, field

I was having a discussion today with one my colleagues in the lab about the independence and co-existence of EM fields.

**My argument:**

1. In time-varying fields: EM fields are necessary dependent, and they have to co-exist. They get coupled through the time derivatives that appears in Maxwell's equations.
2. In static fields: EM fields are independent and each can exist separately or together.

**His argument:**

1. In time-varying fields: (similar to mine)
2. In static fields: EM fields must co-exist. (He is mentioning the spin of the electron about its axis of rotation, and the rotation of the electron around the nucleus and how that induces a magnetic field.)

**Examples to clarify my question:**

- A point charge at rest (for simplicity), has a static E-field around it pointing in the radial direction. (is there a magnetic field?)
- A DC current flowing in a conductor produces an M-field around the conductor. (is there an electric field?)

Comment: Interesting question. I won't try to be funny by saying _This question is off-topic because..._, but rather point you at Physics.SE

Comment: Well, yeah, I guess so (for rigorous proofs). I would argue that electromagnetic is a topic of concern to many disciplines too :)

Comment: Seems like physics.se to me too. AFAIK, the magnetic field around a conductor, caused by the electron flow, is a relativistic effect of the electron drift.

Comment: "I guess so (for rigorous proofs)", so are you simply asking for opinion on ee.se?

Comment: Not opinion, but kind of simple explanation, or pointing out a mistake in my argument.

Comment: If you wanted to be pedantic, you could say there are no static fields because you always have to create them.  But for your static E-field for a charged object there is no B field.  (as long as the charge is constant.. no leakage current.)  For your current case, there is still an E-field in the wire since the wire has some resistance.  You could ask about a super-conducting wire.

Comment: Note that this is on hold because the migration was rejected. The OP had [already asked the same question there](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/135030/17516). Please don't cross-post the same question to multiple sites.